# Static Class returnig null in C# class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shared, class-library

I have a solution that has 3 projects. Using visual studio 2022

project 1: lib (console App)
Class cAgvMgr - Manager class

project 2 - Util(Class Library)
Static Class named AgvMgvinterface

Project 3 - Simulator (class App with forms)
Class Program

I am using the static class named AgvMgrinterface to set the class instance (this) of the class named cAgvMgr so the project-named simulator can access the currently running instance of the CAgvMgr class. I referenced the util project with both the cAgvMgr and the simulator project. I can patt the instance on the cAgvMgr using (this) to the method the static class AgvMgvinterface it is good, but when I go to get the data to use in the Simulator the static class AgvMgrInterface returns a null. I do not understand why? Also is there a better way to accomplish this? I have put the lines of code in bold for the cAgv class and the OverviewUI form code

Any help is appreciated
Thanks Tom

Code Snipts;
cAgvMgr

```
public cAgvMgr(Logger log)
{
    _logger = log;
    Init();
}

private void Init()
{
    _agvList = new List<cAgv>();
    _agvNumbers = new List<int>();

    _config = new Config();
    _config.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigFolder"] + "\\Config.ini");
    Config = _config;

    _numCommPorts = _config.GetIntegerSetting("AGVCOM1.SETTINGS.NCOMPORT");
    //_maxQuietMinutes = _config.GetIntegerSetting("AGV.SETTINGS.MaxQuietAGVEMinutes");

    Setup();
    _comPortManager = new cComPortManager(this);
    _dloadMgr = new cDloadMgr(this);// Create the connection to DLoad manager, TAF
    _kodakAgvStatusMgr = new KodakAgvStatusManager();
    _kodakAgvUtils = new KodakAgvUtils();

    HostAdapter = new cKodakHostAdapter(this);
    HostComManager = new cHostComManager(this);

    Utils.AgvMgrInterface.SetAgvInstance(this); // expose the instance to the static class, TAF, 2/2/23

    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    _timer.Interval = _config.GetIntegerSetting("AGV.SETTINGS.APPCYCLETIMEMS");
    _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

AgvMgrInterface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Utils
{
    public static class AgvMgrInterface
    {
        private static object _agvMgr;
        public static object Instance { get { return _agvMgr; }}

        public static void SetAgvInstance(Object Mgr)
        {
            _agvMgr = Mgr;
        }
    }
}
```

Simulator project form called OverviewUI

```
public OverviewUI(KodakAgvSimulator Parent)
{
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    _parent = Parent;
    _config = new Config();

    _cAgvMgr = (cAgvMgr)Utils.AgvMgrInterface.Instance; //new cAgvMgr(_log);

    _config.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigFolder"] + "\\Config.ini");
    InitializeComponent();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    updateNumberOfAGVs();
    UpdateGrid();
}
```

I did try and use interfaces, moved the static class into the project with cAgvMgr with the same results then created a class library to put the static class into with the same results.

Comment: `_cAgvMgr = (cAgvMgr)Utils.AgvMgrInterface.Instance; //new cAgvMgr(_log);` Does the comment imply that you think the constructor will be called by this line? Because it will not.

Comment: Is your app multithreaded?  Are `AgvMgrInterface.SetAgvInstance()` and `AgvMgrInterface.Instance` being called from different threads?

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Is this supposed to run in _one_ Process? In the beginning of the question it _sounds like_ it is supposed not to, but with this structure it can't. But also, it cannot possibly work without some assumptions being met, that I cannot actually make. So, baseline is: you should go and setup a [mcve].

Comment: `private static object _agvMgr;` and why in the world would throw away typesafety?

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigFolder"] + "\\Config.ini"` => [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) ...

Comment: Is your app multithreaded? Are AgvMgrInterface.SetAgvInstance() and AgvMgrInterface.Instance being called from different threads?   yes the  call AgvMgrinterface.instance is a windows form, which I believe is a differnt thread.

Comment: The class cAgvMgr is instantiated and works, but opens an ethernet port. The project Simulator needs the data from the running instance of cAgvMgr and I cannot instantiate cAgvMgr again since it will create another comm connection that will not work with the project simulation.

Comment: @Fildor I placed a real simple minimal reproducible example on github https://github.com/Ranger541/Minimul_Example. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Again I am confused. That really sounds like you need [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Has your project progressed? I have taken the example you gave. This situation is more suitable for multi-threading.

Comment: We moved the classes and forms into the main project to get the program to work. Thank you for everyones comments and suggestions.